# Cost advantage of removing a property from a model, without updating existing entities?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

If I remove a property from my model, but don't update existing entities, will saving a new entity be cheaper (e.g. will need less write operations) than before?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer is yes.

In the datastore the storage is schemaless, so each record can have its own schema. Less fields: Less data to store, and less indexes to maintain. Other entities in the same kind (table) are independent, so it doesn't matter what you have stored before.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may also need to remove existing indexes on this property.
Anyway, I don't know if removing a single attribute is all that relevant from a performance standpoint, since the datastore duplicates writes so fast anyway.